# Can Different Shiny Pokemon of the Same Species be Different Colours?

Tags: pokemon-series

As it says on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon)

"Upon evolution, a Pokémon will retain its Shiny status. A Shiny Charmander, if leveled up, will eventually become a Shiny Charmeleon and then a Shiny Charizard, just as a regular Charmander will become a regular Charmeleon and then a regular Charizard. This is due to the status being determined by values inherent to the Pokémon;"

So those are the questions:

1. One kind of Pokemon (Example Charmander) can have 2 colors ? 
       **eg: Charmander is red (normal) and his shiny is yellow can another shiny Charmander be black ?**
2. Can a shiny Charmander (yellow) become a black Charmeleon ?

EDIT:

As said in bulbapedia...

"Shiny Pokémon in the games may differ in color from their normal counterparts either very little or very much. Usually the former is the case, with some Pokémon, such as Glaceon or Pichu, having their Shiny form be only a few shades lighter or darker in color, although a majority of the Pokémon that exhibit this are not in their final form of evolution. However, many Pokémon will have a spectacular difference between their normal and Shiny variations; even extremely common Pokémon like Caterpie show a dramatic difference."

So my question (as I said) is about this: "many Pokémon will have a spectacular difference between their normal and Shiny variations". Pokemons **CAN** be shiny even without change they color like [Spiky-eared-Pichu](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Spiky-eared_Pichu).

What I have found about this was:

1. The shiny [Charmander](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Charmander) in Pokemon wiki is Yellow, while the
   [Charizard](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Charizard) is Black.
2. In the Anime there is a [Yellow Magikarp](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magikarp_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), and a [Red Gyarados](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Red_Gyarados), the
   yellow Magikarp appears only in the anime, and it's not a good base of information for the game, but at least give us some extra reference.

So I guess it is YES for question 2.

But in question 1 I'am still not sure. **Can i have two shiny Charmanders one yellow and another Black ?**

Comment: What is wrong with my question ? how can i improve it ? (I am asking because I got downvote and I don't know why... so i can't do nothing about to improve it)

Comment: I can't even comprehend your question, but Raven gives you pretty much all the information on the topic that would answer any question I could glean from your words.

Comment: @StrixVaria Thanks for your reply =) sorry about the understanding of my question. I will try make a better version when I leave the work. About RavenDreamer, I don't think his answer was good.

Comment: @StrixVaria I Hope that my edit could clear your understanding about my question. and you could help me here.

Comment: Related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97543/can-a-shiny-pokemon-be-identified-apart-from-the-sparkle-and-colour

Comment: If you look on serebii.net, you'll see that a shiny Beedrill is supposed to be green, but I once battled a friend who sent out a shiny Beedrill that was entirely silver. I also had a friend tell me he had a Pikachu that was blue with orange cheeks. I didn't believe him because I'd never seen it, but after the silver Beedrill, I think he was telling the truth. Maybe there's a sub category of shiny so rare that almost nobody has ever seen it?

Comment: @crystal - People datamining the games would have seen it long ago.  I think you must be mistaken (or there was some kind of super weird palette error with your cart?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Each unique Pokémon sprite has exactly one normal palette and one shiny palette. *However*, some Pokémon have more than one possible sprite, due to gender, variants, or alternate formes. Each of those can have a different shiny palette.

For example:

- Frillish♂ is blue, but Frillish♀ is pink. Shiny Frillish♂ is teal, while shiny Frillish♀ is salmon pink.
- Basculin can appear as red-striped or blue-striped. Shiny red-striped Basculin has an orange stripe, while shiny blue-striped Basculin has a light blue stripe.
- Shellos found in west Sinnoh are pink, but Shellos found in east Sinnoh are blue. Shiny Shellos are salmon pink in west Sinnoh, and cyan in east Sinnoh.

Generally speaking, if a Pokémon can be found in multiple different colours, its shinies will have different colours from each other.

Further, some shiny Pokémon's evolved forms have very different colour schemes, even if the original Pokémon all had the same colour.

- Shiny Charmander and Charmeleon are yellow, but shiny Charizard is black. (A shiny Charmander will always hatch yellow, and when it evolves to Charizard will always turn black.)
- Shiny Magikarp is gold, but shiny Gyarados is red.

Answer (score 7):

"Shiny" Pokemon have alternate color palettes, but there is still only a single alternate color palette. At least through the fifth generation, any two shiny pokemon of the same species, gender and forme will appear identical.

There are no black charmanders, nor is there any rhyme or reason as to the nature of the color swap. Evolution can result in a similarly modified color... or it can result in something entirely different.

Comment: Hi =) First, as i said (black) was my supposition, i don't think you read that... Second, Look at my Edit...

Comment: This is correct, but I just wanted to note that the alternate colour palette can be vastly different between evolutions. For example, in the latest gen, shiny Charmeleons *are* in fact yellow, but shiny Charizards are all grey.

Comment: Thank you RICK. YOUR answer i think is more accurate that @RavenDreamer. There are any example (link) ? I used black as reference thanks to this image http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:Pok%C3%A9mon_Gallery_Encounter_with_Shining.png

Comment: I found some extra info and add to my last edit, about what @Rick said. what show that you were wrong about the "there is still only a single alternate color palette" +RavenDreamer

Comment: @MichelAyres I am not wrong. [Shiny magikarp are gold.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magikarp_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29#Sprites) Always.

Comment: @MichelAyres It seems like a source of confusion here could be the definition of "a single alternate colour palette". Perhaps a better way to explain is that there is only one single alternate colour palette **per Pokemon**, but there can be multiple alternate colours (eg. yellow/black) **per evolutionary chain**.

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking about the anime then sure. If you're asking about the games then no. The images used for shiny pokemon ingame is prerendered by the artists just as the normal version is, only one image for each. You can catch 100 of the same pokemon in shiny form without any visual differences whatsoever.

Comment: Complete answer. Direct to the point. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

No. All shiny Pokemon of a specific species will appear identical to each other.

Answer (score 0):

In gen 2 there was a glitch in the shiny program that caused a shiny to lack color all together and be completely black ( I had a zubat and ditto this way) but the odds of this were supposedly twice as high as a regular shinies. I have not seen them since gold and silver though.