# Does the shiny encounter rate ever reset?

Tags: pokemon-series

Pretty much just what the title says, does the shiny rate reset? If it does, what are the factors that make it reset? Does my 1 in "X" chance of encounter begin from the start of the game, or every time I power off/on my DS and reload my saved game?

I haven't been able to find any evidence that explains this, so I was hoping to find out here for an experiment that I would like to try.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/93653/30210

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't work exactly like you seem to think it does - it's 1 in 8192 chance.  That doesn't mean there's a hidden counter and that if you fight 8192 battles nonstop that one of them is guaranteed to be a shiny, it just means *on average* that's how many you're likely to end up with over that number of battles.  It's really just one of the many randomly rolled stats that a Pokemon has - you might get lucky or you might get unlucky.  There's nothing you can really do to influence this short of activities that directly alter the rate (stuff like Poke Radar) - normal random encounters will always have these odds.

Comment: You can also increase the chances of _breeding_ a shiny by using the [Masuda Method](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method)

Comment: Right, there are several ways of increasing the chances of obtaining a shiny, but if you're just relying on random encounters it is what it is.  (Even the Masuda method only gives you about six times better odds, which is a massive improvement but still will take some patience.)